# ios::ate does not move into end of the file

Tags: c++, stream

I have this little program.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    fstream f("file.txt", ios::out);
    f << "Hello world!" << endl;
    f.close();

    fstream atEnd("file.txt", ios::out | ios::ate);
    cout << "Position: " << atEnd.tellp() << endl;
    atEnd << "You too" << endl;
    atEnd.close();

    return 0;
}
```

It should open the file, write some content into it, then close it and reopen with again at the end, so the text "You too" should be appended at the end of the file. But the position is always 0 and content is rewritten: https://www.onlinegdb.com/online_c++_compiler. Why does this happen? According to documentation the `ios::ate` should *seek to the end of stream immediately after open*.

Comment: consider using ios_base::app (append) flag for that purpose, rather than ios::ate

Answer (score 0):

I think append mode would suffice what you are trying to do :
`fstream f.open("file.txt", ios::app );`

Alternatively you can also use seekp before writing, although it isn't preferred.

Comment: But with `ios::app` I cannot seek in the file. It seems that `ios::out` always truncate the file, because when I use `ios::out | ios::in | ios::ate` it's working correctly. But what if I want to open file for writing and I don't have permissions to read it?

Comment: I think I may have conveyed it in wrong way. seekp is only when you open the file in out or ate mode. Using app mode, you can avoid all that stuff. Additionally I think if you have write permission, you also have read permission.

Comment: If you prefer using ate mode only, use it in combination with in for writing as out would truncate it i.e., ios::ate | ios::in